# Mounting TV on metal studs?

Tags: mounting, studs, metal, television, mount

The wall contains metal studs 24 inch apart.  On a previous TV, I installed an articulating TV mount (80lbs total with mount) on two metal studs with 4 snap toggles (that's 2 snap toggles per metal stud)  The snap toggles are suppose to support up to 80lbs each.  So i'm guessing with 4 snap toggles that equates to 4 x 80 = 320lbs distributed among two metal studs.  However, my TV and mount is only 80lbs, so I thought that would be fine and haven't had any issues yet.

The question is:

1. I haven't really used the articulating full motion aspect of the mount yet. It seems pretty sturdy, but I've never dealt with metal stud before as support.  Should I be afraid that If i move it around that it could rip out of the wall?

So I have another TV that I need to mount. With the dimensions of the room, it looks like I can only use one metal stud.  The TV is also lighter, so with the mount it'll be around 70lbs for a 43 inch LCD and the mount will be an articulating (ex. [http://www.amazon.com/VideoSecu-ML531BE-Monitor-Articulating-Extension/dp/B000WYVBR0/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1458420321&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WYVBR0)) which is meant to be mounted only on one stud as well.

The question is:

1. Can I mount the TV (70lbs) attached to one metal stud with two snap toggles rated at 80lbs each?

Any advice appreciated! 
Thanks,
D

Comment: I recommend two 24" horizontal 2x10s  screwed to the studs on both sides.  This means sheet rock repair and painting.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to remove drywall to add wood structural support to the inside of the wall you could take a piece of cabinet grade 3/4 plywood and attach it to to the wall so it spans two studs and is bolted to the the metal studs, stain finish it or paint it to match the wall. You could use dimensional lumber as well if you are not as picky about appearance.

Cut it wide enough to span the studs, 28". Attach it to the studs with toggle anchors, at least 4, one at each corner, but 3 per side would be better. Then you can use heavy duty toggles to secure the mount to the wood.

Answer (score 0):

I expect you'll have issues as time passes with the TV on 2 studs, it's really just the drywall that's holding it and the steel is just currently keeping it from ripping out. I'd consider 1 stud for the same weight to be a very risky setup and much worse than the already borderline 2 stud one. You'd really want to have big wood (2x8 or more) between wood stud filled (floor to ceiling) steel studs back there.